# bindkey not working from inside .cshrc file

Tags: terminal, keybindings, command-line

Here is my .cshrc:

```
echo Enter
bindkey ^Z run-fg-editor
bindkey ^[OA history-search-backward
bindkey ^[OB history-search-forward
bindkey ^[[A history-search-backward
bindkey ^[[B history-search-forward
echo Exit
```

"Enter" and "Exit" both get printed, but the keybinding is not working.
If I try to execute the same commands, or source the .cshrc again, it works. Can anyone tell me what is happening?

```
tcsh --version
tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-apple-darwin) options wide,nls,dl,bye,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
```